# Why the other checked radio input and label is not working?

Tags: html, css, input, label, checked

[This](https://codepen.io/KookyMonster/pen/oNxYWNQ?editors=1000) makes my questions more clear.

1. I have exactly the same two htmls -  A and B.
   They share the same css, why is A working and B not working??
2. And how can I reverse the heart checked? To make the checked hearts from left to right.

I've tried flexbox, but it is difficult to make a container for inputs and labels. Input and label seems inseparable how to do layouts?

I've also tried to use the properties, input:nth-of-type(5), to change orders.

html:

```
<div class="game">
  <h1>A</h1>
    <div class="b">
      <div class="streaming-info">
        <input type="radio" id="h1" name="heart" value="heart">
        <input type="radio" id="h2" name="heart" value="heart">
        <input type="radio" id="h3" name="heart" value="heart">
        <input type="radio" id="h4" name="heart" value="heart">
        <input type="radio" id="h5" name="heart" value="heart">
        
        <label for="h1" class="viewers"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></label>
        <label for="h2" class="viewers"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></label>
        <label for="h3" class="viewers"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></label>
        <label for="h4" class="viewers"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></label>
        <label for="h5" class="viewers"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></label>
      </div>
      <div class="btnDiv">
        <button class="btn"><a href="#">Reviews</a></button>
        <button class="btn"><a href="#">Buy</a></button>
      </div>

    </div> 
  </div>

<div class="game">
  <h1>B</h1>
    <div class="b">
      <div class="streaming-info">
        <input type="radio" id="h1" name="heart" value="heart">
        <input type="radio" id="h2" name="heart" value="heart">
        <input type="radio" id="h3" name="heart" value="heart">
        <input type="radio" id="h4" name="heart" value="heart">
        <input type="radio" id="h5" name="heart" value="heart">
        
        <label for="h1" class="viewers"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></label>
        <label for="h2" class="viewers"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></label>
        <label for="h3" class="viewers"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></label>
        <label for="h4" class="viewers"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></label>
        <label for="h5" class="viewers"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></label>
      </div>
      <div class="btnDiv">
        <button class="btn"><a href="#">Reviews</a></button>
        <button class="btn"><a href="#">Buy</a></button>
      </div>

    </div> 
  </div>
```

SCSS:

```css
.stats{
  display: flex;
}
.streaming-info >input{
  // order: 1; 
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -999;
}
label:nth-of-type(5){
  order: 2;
}
label:nth-of-type(4){
  order:3;
}
label:nth-of-type(3){
  order:4;
}
label:nth-of-type(2){
  order:5;
}
label:nth-of-type(1){
  order:6;
}

input:nth-of-type(1):hover  ~label:nth-of-type(1),
input:nth-of-type(2):hover  ~label:nth-of-type(2),
input:nth-of-type(3):hover  ~label:nth-of-type(3),
input:nth-of-type(4):hover  ~label:nth-of-type(4),
input:nth-of-type(5):hover  ~label:nth-of-type(5){
  color: red;
}
input:nth-of-type(5):checked  ~label:nth-of-type(n+5),
input:nth-of-type(4):checked  ~label:nth-of-type(n+4),
input:nth-of-type(3):checked  ~label:nth-of-type(n+3),
input:nth-of-type(2):checked  ~label:nth-of-type(n+2),
input:nth-of-type(1):checked  ~label:nth-of-type(n+1){
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap all your inputs inside `form` tag. then update your CSS accordingly.

Try this,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="game">
    <h1>A</h1>
    <div class="b">
      <div class="streaming-info">
        <form>
          <input type="radio" id="h1" name="heart" value="heart">
          <input type="radio" id="h3" name="heart" value="heart">
          <input type="radio" id="h4" name="heart" value="heart">
          <input type="radio" id="h5" name="heart" value="heart">
          <input type="radio" id="h6" name="heart" value="heart">

          <label for="h1" class="viewers"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></label>
          <label for="h2" class="viewers"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></label>
          <label for="h3" class="viewers"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></label>
          <label for="h4" class="viewers"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></label>
          <label for="h5" class="viewers"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></label>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="btnDiv">
        <button class="btn"><a href="#">Reviews</a></button>
        <button class="btn"><a href="#">Buy</a></button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="game">
    <h1>B</h1>
    <div class="b">
      <div class="streaming-info">
        <form>
          <input type="radio" id="h2" name="heart" value="heart">
          <input type="radio" id="h2" name="heart" value="heart">
          <input type="radio" id="h2" name="heart" value="heart">
          <input type="radio" id="h2" name="heart" value="heart">
          <input type="radio" id="h2" name="heart" value="heart">

          <label for="h1" class="viewers"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></label>
          <label for="h2" class="viewers"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></label>
          <label for="h3" class="viewers"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></label>
          <label for="h4" class="viewers"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></label>
          <label for="h5" class="viewers"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></label>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="btnDiv">
        <button class="btn"><a href="#">Reviews</a></button>
        <button class="btn"><a href="#">Buy</a></button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps you a bit :)

Answer (score -1):

have you tried adding the same class name for the two html?

> 

Comment: Please , add details and make the answer clear to the best of your capabilities.

Comment: A and B htmls are two identicals.